# Multiple tmpdir for MySQL

Tags: mysql

As per https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/temporary-files.html,

> The --tmpdir option can be set to a list of several paths that are
> used in round-robin fashion. Paths should be separated by colon
> characters (:) on Unix and semicolon characters (;) on Windows.

On our Linux system (`Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS`) we changed the MySQL config file as follows:

```
[mysqld]
#...
tmpdir=/tmp:/mysql_tmp
```

However, when we try to run `sudo service mysql restart` following the change, we are getting the following error:

```
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
```

---

**Question:** Can we set up multiple tmpdirs in the MySQL config files?

Comment: May be you could look in the MySQL error log for the actual error message?

Comment: Does it give the error code number?

Comment: Do not alter config file, edit service command line. Try to enclose separate paths with quote chars. Start MySQL server from the command line and look for error messages.